# How do I validate start date and end date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

What's the best way to validate that the end date is not before the start date, and start date is after the end date in Rails?

I have this in my view controller:

```
<tr>
    <td><%= f.label text="Starts:" %></td>
    <td><%= f.datetime_select :start_date, :order => [:day, :month, :year]%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%= f.label text="Ends:" %></td>
    <td><%= f.datetime_select :end_date,:order => [:day, :month, :year]</td>
</tr>
```

I want it to come up with a popup of sorts, with a meaningful message.

I would like to make a generic method that takes two parameters, start and end date, which I then can call in my viewcontroller ; `fx` in the code above. Or, do I need to use jQuery instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want client side validation, use jQuery.

Or in rails, to validate server side, you could create your own I guess?

```
def date_validation
  if self[:end_date] < self[:start_date]
    errors[:end_date] << "Error message"
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end
```

**Rails >= 7.0 makes this a one-liner**

`validates_comparison_of :end_date, greater_than_or_equal_to: :end_date`

[PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/536a2c0011e0297b8382f8ad4c7d42433b08ea82), [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#comparison)

Comment: why one need to return truth value from `date_validation`?

Answer (score 14):

@YaBoyQuy
client-side validation can work and avoids a hit to the server...

The question is also about end_date being after the start, so the validation - using gem `date_validator` -  should also state

```
validates :end_date, presence: true, date: { after_or_equal_to:  :start_date}
```

The suggestion of

```
on: :create
```

would be incorrect for the end_date validation; logically this should also be run on an edit.

I upvoted on the basis of the succinct syntax.

Comment: This answer is very readable, but it requires the `date_validator` validation gem. It's not available in vanilla Rails.

Answer (score 9):

### Clean and Clear (and under control?)

I find this to be the clearest to read:

#### In Your Model

```
validates_presence_of :start_date, :end_date

validate :end_date_is_after_start_date


#######
private
#######

def end_date_is_after_start_date
  return if end_date.blank? || start_date.blank?

  if end_date < start_date
    errors.add(:end_date, "cannot be before the start date") 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Avoid client side validation, because it only validate client side...
Use the rails validaters built in.

```
  validates :start_date, presence: true, date: { after_or_equal_to: Proc.new { Date.today }, message: "must be at least #{(Date.today + 1).to_s}" }, on: :create
  validates :end_date, presence: true
```

Comment: Yes, above code is chunk of https://github.com/codegram/date_validator else it will throw error.

Answer (score 2):

to use your `validates :dt_end, :date => {:after_or_equal_to => :dt_start}` you need to have a `DateValidator` such as this:

```
class DateValidator > ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    the_end = record.dt_end
    the_start = record.dt_start
    if the_end.present?
      if the_end < the_start
        record.errors[:dt_end] << "The end date can't be before the start date. Pick a date after #{the_start}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```